# My SCCM 2007 SQL Web Report is not displaying results

Tags: sql, sccm, sccm-2007

I created an SCCM SQL report using SQL Management Studio. I then created the following prompts for my Asset Management Office to use on the web report: Publisher, Display Name, and Version.

The Display Name and the Version prompts are both optional.

I receive no syntax errors or anything, but I receive absolutely no results whatsoever when I click on the Display button to produce the web report.

Here is my SQL code:

==================================================================================

**SELECT**     dbo.v_R_System.Netbios_Name0, dbo.v_GS_ADD_REMOVE_PROGRAMS.DisplayName0, dbo.v_GS_ADD_REMOVE_PROGRAMS.Version0, 
                      dbo.v_GS_ADD_REMOVE_PROGRAMS.Publisher0

**FROM**         dbo.v_R_System INNER JOIN
                      dbo.v_GS_ADD_REMOVE_PROGRAMS ON dbo.v_R_System.ResourceID = dbo.v_GS_ADD_REMOVE_PROGRAMS.ResourceID

**WHERE**       dbo.v_GS_ADD_REMOVE_PROGRAMS.DisplayName0 = @DisplayName AND dbo.v_GS_ADD_REMOVE_PROGRAMS.Version0 = @Version AND dbo.v_GS_ADD_REMOVE_PROGRAMS.Publisher0 = @Publisher

**Order by** dbo.v_GS_ADD_REMOVE_PROGRAMS.DisplayName0 ASC

==================================================================================

I run my report and in the Publisher prompt, I type in something like %Autodesk% and then I click the Display button, and absolutely nothing is displayed. I can go to another report and look up Autodesk products, but not this one. I am not a well versed SQL guy, so if anyone can help me that would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

% signs often mean wildcards.  They are used with the like keyword.  You have equal signs.  In other words,

```
where DisplayName like '%fred%'
```

will return fred, freddie, frederick, etc.  However,

```
where DisplayName = '%fred%'
```

will only return %fred%

Comment: No, my prompts are working just fine, so the "@variables" that you see are correct. In SCCM when you create an SQL Web Report, you can also create a Prompt and add extra SQL code to that, then you give it a name and it links it to one of your @variables. The equal sign needs to be there to tell SCCM that whatever the user inputs into the prompt is going to equate to that variable and then to use those values to show the results in the report. Something else is amiss here, but I cannot see what the hell it is. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

AHHHH I see what you were talking about Dan.

Disregard my last statement/inquiry everyone, I got my code working now. My Prompt @variables' SQL code was not configured properly to work with the "Like" constant so I modified my main SQL code to be this:

================================================================================== 
Select Distinct dbo.v_R_System.Netbios_Name0, dbo.v_GS_ADD_REMOVE_PROGRAMS.DisplayName0, dbo.v_GS_ADD_REMOVE_PROGRAMS.Version0, dbo.v_GS_ADD_REMOVE_PROGRAMS.Publisher0 
FROM dbo.v_R_System 
Join dbo.v_GS_ADD_REMOVE_PROGRAMS On dbo.v_R_System.ResourceID = dbo.v_GS_ADD_REMOVE_PROGRAMS.ResourceID 
Where dbo.v_GS_ADD_REMOVE_PROGRAMS.Publisher0 Like @Publisher Or dbo.v_GS_ADD_REMOVE_PROGRAMS.DisplayName0 Like @DisplayName Or dbo.v_GS_ADD_REMOVE_PROGRAMS.Version0 Like @VersionOrder by dbo.v_GS_ADD_REMOVE_PROGRAMS.DisplayName0 ASC

==================================================================================

Then I had to modify my Prompt SQL code to use the Begin, If, Else, and End statements. I will pick just my @Publisher variable Prompt SQL code since all of my Prompt @variables' SQL code are basically identical.

Here is the SQL code for my Publisher (@Publisher) Prompt:

==================================================================================

Begin
If(@__filterwildcard = '')
Select Distinct Publisher0
From v_Add_Remove_Programs Order By Publisher0
Else
Select Distinct Publisher0 
From v_Add_Remove_Programs
Where Publisher0 Like @__filterwildcard
Order By Publisher0
End

==================================================================================

The code I used before for my Prompt @variables was like this which did not work with the "Like" constant in my main SQL code:

==================================================================================

Select Distinct Publisher0
From v_Add_Remove_Programs Order By Publisher0 
Where Publisher0 Like @__filterwildcard
Order By Publisher0

==================================================================================

So, apparently using the Begin, If, Else, and End statements allowed for more logic in this query process, therefore allowing me to use the "Like" constant in my main SQL code for the report.